# How to use variables in the Application Lab interface to Workload Scheduler on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, workload-scheduler

I'm trying to use the *Application Lab* application on Bluemix's *Workload Scheduler* service but can't find any documentation on how to use it.  Specifically, I need to run a RESTful URL once a day, with a timestamp of the previous run embedded in the URL.
Creating variables in *Application Lab* seems pretty straightforward, but I can't figure out how to set or use them.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update of the variables of the application lab via APIs is not yet available (it will be soon).

There is another way of doing it that I can share with you.
Follow these steps:

**Enable the cloud agent to run scripts**

You should open a ticket for that. By defaults the cloud agent is not enabled to run scripts but you can open a ticket to change this.

**Get the user credentials**

Open the service a take not of the user credentials. Click "Add credentials" if they are not present.
[image]

**Open the Workload Editor**

The workload editor is a more powerful UI with respect to the Application Lab and enable complex scenarios.

To open the Workload Designer, open the Application Lab, right click on a process and select "Launch Workload Designer".

[image]

**Define the restful job**

Create a new restful job:

[image]

Then set the name and the workstations and check the flag "Variable resolution at runtime".

[image]

Then click on the "Action" pane and set the URI of the service. Add the ${TIMESTAMP} variable in the URI. For testing purposes I used this URI:

http://echo.jsontest.com/title/ipsum/content/${TIMESTAMP}

[image]

Save this definition (use the floppy disk icon).

**Define the job that updates the variable**

Create an executable job:

[image]

Set the name, the workstation and the "Variable resolution at runtime" flag

[image]

Then open the "Task pane" and add the following in the script field:

```
#/bin/sh -x
#Set the following 3 variables from your credentials
export USERNAME="xxxxxx@bluemix.net"
export PASSWORD='xxxxxx' 
export HOSTNAME=xxxxx.wa.ibmserviceengage.com

#Replace "CC" with the letters of your tenant
export VT=CCTIMESTAMP

#MAIN STARTS HERE
export TIMESTAMP=`date +%s`

. /home/wauser/TWA/TWS/tws_env.sh

echo "VARTABLE $VT MEMBERS TIMESTAMP \"$TIMESTAMP\" END" > /home/wauser/vt.txt

composer -host $HOSTNAME  -protocol https -username "$USERNAME" -password $PASSWORD replace  /home/wauser/vt.txt
```

[image]
Save the job.

Submit the job by clicking "Select Action" -> "Submit Job into current plan".

[image]

**Define a job stream**

Click "New" -> "Job Stream"

Define the name, the workstation and the variable table (replace CC with your two letters tenant id).
The right click on and select add jobs:

[image]

Add the "TEST" and "UPDATETIMESTAMP" jobs (or the name you used).

Right click on "UPDATETIMESTAMP" and select "Add dependencies" -> "Job in the same job stream" and then select "TEST".

[image]

Right click on "Run Cycles" and select "Add Run Cycle"

[image]

Open the "Rule" pane and select "Daily"

[image]

Open the "Time Restrictions" and set the time when the job stream has to start and check the flag "use as time dependency".

[image]

Save the job stream and you're done!